# Google Maps API v2 - Using API Key with built-in map app

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

If the built-in google-maps app is started via an intent, like so

```
string maps = "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
string addr = "center=422+Android+Blvd+10110";
string key = "key=Ab4jk3j4k34jk34jk3"

string url =  "http://" + maps + "?" + addr + "&" + key

Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
StartActivityForResult(intent,(int)ActivityRequestCode.Map);
```

can an API-key be specified in the request's url so that it will be serviced in the same way as when
using them in requests from the v2 MapFragment/MapActivity/MapView ?

I think all my syntax and such is correct, because the first request I made today was fulfilled, but all subsequent requests have been ignored.  It's as if the service is enforcing it's abuse policy against my IP.

A debug.keystore file was used to extract the SHA signature from, and an entry was made in the manifest file with the generated key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application>       
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:value="Ab4jk3j4k34jk34jk3" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Since my requests are being ignored, I think maybe the built-in maps app doesn't support requests with keys specified in them.  There are technical limitations as to why I cannot use the newer v2 style MapFragment/MapActivity (or whatever it's called).

I've tried three key types, two "browser apps" and one "android apps":

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Which permissions do you have set?

Comment: @Cheesebaron OP updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps v2 - Intent URI Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881689/google-maps-v2-intent-uri-arguments/18882080#18882080)

Answer (score 1):

The browser API key differs from the mobile application API key, so you will not be able to use the API key you have generated from your keystore as it is only for your app.

Using static (browser) maps is afaik without keys, however if you are displaying a map on a specific domain on a web page you will need to use an API key.

Comment: Thanks CB. We'll, I was given 3 keys from the Google Console, two  "browser apps" and a "android apps" key, and have tried them all  (updated OP with screen shot) ? If I try without key, then only the first request I make that day (ie, within 24hrs) gets serviced, all others get dropped thereafter (with or without key).

Comment: ... Your right though, according to the **staticmaps** docs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=nl#api_key it states **Note that the use of a key is not required, though it is recommended. Examples in this document do not include the key parameter so that they will work for all users who cut-and-paste the code.**