# Google Maps v2 - Intent URI Arguments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-2

I'm launching the builtin Maps app (7.1.0) via an Intent, however none of the request url's I'm sending it seem to be working.

I was wondering what the correct syntax is for the url/uri argument.

I thought it was a static-map request, but the built-in map app isn't a static map, and is probably why they do not work.

The older style v1 request strings do not work either.

Is it even possible to send requests to the map app via a url/uri intent argument since v2 ?

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated (I just want to use the built-in map app, and feel I shouldn't have to implement my own MapActivity/Fragment, since I'm not doing anything fancy, just a simple plot).

Here is the code that fires the map:

```
//string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?geo:50.95144,6.98725?q=50.95144,6.98725%20(Disneyland)&zoom=13&size=600x300&sensor=true";
//string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&sensor=true";
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY";

Uri uri = Uri.Parse( url );

Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));

intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Thank you.

Comment: string url = "geo:0,0?q=0,0"; works, so I guess I don't need the scheme and server address, just the query-params.

Comment: You would also be advised to get rid of the `setClassName()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare is setClassName depreciated (so to speak) ?  I'm using it here as a hint to the OS as to which app the request should be serviced by. How in the world can Android deduce the correct app with such limited info (ie, the uri request "geo:0,0?q=0,0" (It does work without tho)) ??

Comment: "I'm using here as a hint to the OS as to which app the request should be serviced by" -- any use of `setClassName()` is a serious code smell and should be avoided where possible, as it makes your app fragile and user-hostile. "How in the world can Android deduce the correct app with such limited info (ie, the uri request "geo:0,0?q=0,0" ?" -- the same way it can "deduce the correct app" for `http` and other schemes. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot for the insight... I didn't realize "geo" was a scheme, but now I see, its "geo:" not "geo="... thought it was a param!

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the **query parameters** and their values, and omit the **uri scheme** (http://), **server name** (maps.googleapis.com) and **resource path** (/maps/api).

However, the center param doesn't seem to work (for me anyway)

```
string url = "center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY"
```

so as a work around, I use the geo and q params together

```
string url = "geo:0,0?q=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY";
```

OR

```
string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=new+york";
```